How to report on a users sign in activity and manager using Get-MgUser
I need to write a PowerShell script to report on a users sign in activity both interactive and non-interactive and include who their line manager is as well. The end goal is to use my app registration to send the managers emails automatically after but I just want the get the basic script working first, which I can't. I currently have the below but struggling to get the managers name even displayed in the results? (I know I am missing manager in the pscustomobject, i think there is a bigger issue with my script).
# User properties to report on
$properties = "ID", "UserPrincipalName", "DisplayName", "JobTitle", "AccountEnabled", "OnPremisesSyncEnabled", "CreatedDateTime", "SignInActivity", "Manager"

# Filter through users and expand manager property
$allUsers = Get-MgUser -All -Property $properties -ExpandProperty Manager

# Initialize an empty array
$output = @()

# Loop through each user and add elements to the empty array
foreach ($user in $allUsers) {
    $output += [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ID'                                        = $user.ID
        'User Principal Name'                       = $user.UserPrincipalName
        'Display Name'                              = $user.DisplayName
        'Job Title'                                 = $user.JobTitle
        'Account Enabled'                           = $user.AccountEnabled
        'On Prem Sync Enabled'                      = $user.OnPremisesSyncEnabled
        'Created Date Time'                         = $user.CreatedDateTime
        'Last Interactive Sign In Date Time'        = $lastSignInDateTime
        'Last Non-Interactive Sign In Date Time'    = $lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime
    }
}

$output | Format-Table -AutoSize

I've been told previously that User Graph API doesn't support retrieving the user's manager and signInActivity in a single query, therefore I need to perform 2 queries for each user but doing something like the below takes absolutely ages to run, plus it's not in the format of what I am trying to achieve above?
$getMgUserSplat = @{
    ExpandProperty = 'Manager'
    All            = $true
    Property       = @(
        'DisplayName'
        'UserPrincipalName'
        'JobTitle'
        'Manager'
    )
}

Get-MgUser @getMgUserSplat | ForEach-Object {
    $signIn = Get-MgUser -UserId $_.Id -Select SignInActivity

    [pscustomobject]@{
        DisplayName        = $_.DisplayName
        UserPrincipalName  = $_.UserPrincipalName
        JobTitle           = $_.JobTitle
        ManagerDisplayName = $_.Manager.AdditionalProperties['displayName']
        ManagerEmail       = $_.Manager.AdditionalProperties['mail']
        LastSignInDateTime = $signIn.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
    }
} | Export-Csv path\to\myExport.csv -NoTypeInformation


You can get both (manager and signInActivity) in single call if you directly query the user endpoint. I do not know if you can do this with Get-MgUser, I don't use the cmdlets from the Graph Module except for Invoke-MgGraphRequest.

Worth noting, in order to query signInActivity:

Details for this property require a Microsoft Entra ID P1 or P2 license and the AuditLog.Read.All permission.
This property isn't returned for a user who never signed in or last signed in before April 2020.


This is how the code looks with a direct API call:
$select = @(
    'id'
    'userPrincipalName'
    'displayName'
    'jobTitle'
    'accountEnabled'
    'onPremisesSyncEnabled'
    'createdDateTime'
    'signInActivity'
) -join ','

$uri = "v1.0/users?`$select=$select&`$expand=manager"

$output = do {
    $req = Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET $uri
    $uri = $req.'@odata.nextLink'

    foreach ($user in $req.value) {
        # NOTE: `$user.manager` contains other manager properties.
        #       add more to the pscustomobject if needed if needed

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'ID'                                     = $user.id
            'User Principal Name'                    = $user.userPrincipalName
            'Display Name'                           = $user.displayName
            'Manager Display Name'                   = $user.manager.displayName
            'Job Title'                              = $user.jobTitle
            'Account Enabled'                        = $user.accountEnabled
            'On Prem Sync Enabled'                   = $user.onPremisesSyncEnabled
            'Created Date Time'                      = $user.createdDateTime
            'Last Interactive Sign In Date Time'     = $user.signInActivity.lastSignInDateTime
            'Last Non-Interactive Sign In Date Time' = $user.signInActivity.lastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime
        }
    }
}
while ($uri)

$output | Format-Table

